# Changing global variables and read them

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables, python-2.x, configparser

I have properties file **props.properties**

```
[collect_data]
collect = True
```

And 2 files **test2.py**

```
import test1 as c


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def printer(self):
        print 'in test2 value is' c.COLLECT_DATA
```

And **test1.py** file with main function

```
    from ConfigParser import ConfigParser    
    import test2 as t

    DEFAULT_PROPS = '..//etc//props.properties'

    COLLECT_DATA = False

    class Initializer:
        def __init__(self):
            pass

        def init_const(self, properties=DEFAULT_PROPS):
            cfg = ConfigParser()
            print 'Start'
            cfg.read(properties)
            global COLLECT_DATA = False
            COLLECT_DATA = eval(cfg.get('collect_data', 'collect'))
            print 'Now it is', COLLECT_DATA 

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        i = Initializer()
        i.init_const()

        test = t.Test()
        test.printer()
        print COLLECT_DATA
```

I want to read properties from props file, assing it and read them in another file, but actually I have such logs:

```
Start
Now it True
in test2 value is False
True
```

How to solve it?

Comment: What is test1??

Comment: Why would you like to do this? Usually working with global variables is not a good approach and your problem can be better fixed another way

Comment: @Nathan to flexibly manage properties without building an application every time when i want to change global-vars. What other way are you told about?

Comment: Firstly, `tp.Test()`: isn't it supposed to be `t.Test()`? Secondly, `How to solve it?`: You have a circular dependency, read about it [here](https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/) and try to fix it.

Comment: @AjayDabas about tp (my mistake in post creating)

Comment: @TarasDanylchenko sorry if I was unclear, do you need global variables? In my experience they always end up breaking everything

Comment: @Nathan unfortunately yes

Comment: @TarasDanylchenko are you sure? Would it be possible to have for instance a `main.py` which tracks all the variables which you then pass to your files? Effectively the same functionality, but it would make tracking and altering variables much easier.